# thermistor in HC-SR501 PIR

Tags: sensor, thermistor, pir

i know the effects of soldering photo-resistor to HC-SR501 PIR module. It then detects movement in the dark only. But can anyone tell me that what is the effect of adding a thermistor to the same PIR module? There is a provision in module itself to solder both photoresistor and thermistor. I searched on the internet but in vain. I m sure someone here can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I plan to use this outdoors in Canada, where temps may go to -30C or lower in the winter. The sensor is rated -15 to 70 (presumably Fahrenheit). Guess it won't work as intended!

Comment: It may work under -15C - but its not guaranteed to.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you searched on the internet, but the very [first document](https://www.mpja.com/download/31227sc.pdf) popping up in Google has this:

> Temperature compensation (optional, factory reset): In the summer when the ambient temperature rises to 30 ° C to 32 ° C, the detection distance is slightly shorter, temperature compensation can be used for performance compensation.

The [second document](https://dronebotworkshop.com/using-pir-sensors-with-arduino-raspberry-pi/) has this:

> The HC-SR501 circuit board has solder pads for two additional components. These are usually labeled.
>   **RT** – This is meant for a thermistor or temperature-sensitive resistor.  Adding this allows the HC-SR501 to be used in extreme temperatures, it also increases the accuracy of the detector to some degree.
>   **RL** – This connection is for a Light Dependent Resistor (LDR) or Photoresistor.  By adding this component the HC-SR501 will only operate in darkness, a common application for motion-sensitive lighting systems.

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply... Lesson learned- ALWAYS THOROUGHLY CHECK THE DATASHEET.

Answer (score 1):

> Temperature compensation (optional, factory reset): In the summer when the ambient temperature rises to 30 ° C to 32 ° C, the detection
>   distance is slightly shorter, temperature compensation can be used for performance compensation.

This schematic shows RT1=1M  ( rated at 25'C)

In order to increase the sensitivity of the sensor with a rise in ambient temp. an NTC thermistor is used to increase the range with higher ambient.  Although there are a variety of Beta gain factors for NTC's no other information seems to be given.

Here the sensitivity is limited by R13=10k and this board has an opearting range from Temperature: – 15 ~ +70

So I would expect the RT1 to drop from 1M @ 25'C towards 10k @ 70'C
[REF SCHEMA](https://www.mpja.com/download/31227sc.pdf)
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So what I now gather from your comment is that 
- PIR range(or sensivity) decrease as temperature rises. 
- Adding NTC thermistor will counter any sensitivity loss due to temperature rise.

I have one doubt though. It appears that PIR sensor are prone to false detection when temperature rises. Does soldering thermistor can reduce this particular error? I hope that you can shed some light on this.

Comment: I see.  Perhaps "detection distance is slightly shorter, " means more likely to false trigger.   I have never used them.